# How to make URL from Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, api, http, laravel-5

I've got Laravel backend and I'm trying to make iOS to it, but there is no documentation.
It is my first time with Laravel, so confused with the routes and middlewares.
How do I compose URL from code below

````
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
   return $request->user();
});

// Passport authentication
Route::group([
   'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
   Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
   Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');

   Route::group([
     'middleware' => 'auth:api'
   ], function() {
       Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
       Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
       Route::resource('materials', 'MaterialsController');
       Route::resource('packages', 'PackagesController'); ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full path of your routes are the result of composition of some parts:

- Base URL (domain, subdomain, IP)
- Route prefix(es) (optional)
- Route definition (basically, your endpoint)

Taking the following route defined in the `web.php` as an example:

```
// web.php
Route::get('my-cool-route', MyCoolController::class);
```

Then, that endpoint will have the following full path:

```
foobar.com/my-cool-route
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> The `foobar.com`part will be pulled out from the `APP_URL` key of your `.env` file

You could also have routes already prefixed (by you or by Laravel), for example the ones written inside the `api.php` file:

```
// api.php
Route::get('register', SignUpController::class);
```

By default, the routes inside `api.php` will be prefixed with `api`. So the route will look like this:

```
foobar.com/api/register
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In case you wonder where this prefix is added, you can go to `RouteServiceProvider.php` to see [how this is applied](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/bec982b0a3962c8a3e1f665e987360bb8c056298/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L41).

You can output the list of your routes with the help of Artisan.

```
php artisan route:list
```

Of course, this will throw ALL your site routes, so you could filter them by a lot of options like `path` por example:

```
php artisan route:list --path='materials'
```

That will list all the routes with a path that matches `%materials%`.

You can use the `--help` (or `-h`) option to see the full list of filter options.

Comment: Beautiful answer, thanks! I manage to get list of routes through `php artisan route:list` but when I got to foobar.com it show `Error 403 - Forbidden` and Laravel is running on localhost:8000, also I created local database on MAMP, what should I do ?

Comment: @GabrielBalta I forgot to mention that the `php artisan route:list` command only show routes without the base URI (so, only the relative part of the route)

Answer (score 2):

Name your routes and use the `route()` helper to get the full URL to the route. For example;

```
// In routes/web.php
Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout')->name('auth.logout');

// Anywhere in your context
route('auth.logout'); // will return full URL, e.g; 'http://localhost/logout'
```

For more details, see this links;

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route

Comment: I'm not at all sure what Gabriel Balta is confused about.... but this is  certainly a good reply.  I'm crossing my fingers that it answers his question!

Comment: @paulsm4 as I said it is my first time using Laravel, and I saw some middleware with syntax ('/login') and then routes with ('login') so this cause confusion for me as for building URL in app to contact api, was not sure about using / all the time or not. The answer is right it explains the thing. Thanks !